# What is the difference between "As if!" and other similar discourse markers?

Tags: english, slang, interjections

According to Oxford Dictionary of English 3rd edition (2010:90), discourse marker “as if” means, in informal style, “I very much doubt it.” Oxford English Dictionary 3rd edition explains that “as if” as discourse marker is “typically used as a sardonic response to a stated or reported suggestion.” Genius English-Japanese Dictionary 5th edition (GEJD5) (2014:123) presents the following example.

> (1) “Did you have a good flight?” “As if!” ( = It was definitely not a good flight!) (GEJD5)

Inoue (2017:459) states that “As if!” is similar to “Not!,” “Yeah, right!,” “No way!,” “Whatever!” and so on. Tunnicliffe (2013:11) states that it resembles “No chance!” Let me show you each usage and example of “As if!” and other similar discourse markers cited from dictionaries as follows.

> (2) “[As if! is] An expression of annoyance, to show disapproval of a suggestion, statement, explanation, etc.; “I’m going to take you out for a meal on Saturday” “As if! You’ve said that so many times before,  and never done it!”” (Manser (1983:9))
>
> (3) “[Not. is] used as a humorous cancellation of what has just been said in jest: “Yeah, but you’ve got a boyfriend now.” “Not,” I said, emphatically, appropriating one of her more asinine pop phrases.”    (Dalzell and Victor (2013:1596))
>
> (4) “[Yeah, right. is] used to say that you do not believe what sb [somebody] has just said, disagree with it, or are not interested in it: “You’ll be fine.” “Yeah, right.”” (OALDCE9)
>
> (5) “[No way. is] used for expressing disbelief at that which has just been said: “I suppose you have every reason to regard me as a certified nut case.” “No way.”” (Dalzell and Victor (2013:1599))
>
> (6) “[Whatever! is] used as a dismissing retort to what has just been said: ELTON: I think we both know what it feels like to be lonely. CHER: Whatever.” (Dalzell and Victor (2013:2399))
>
> (7) “[No chance! is] used as an emphatic negative, often scornful: MONICA: But it’s my chance, Johnny. It’s my only chance. JOHNNY: No chance.” (Dalzell and Victor (2013:1586))

Now I wonder what the radical difference between “As if!” and the others is. If you had lucid answers and explained to me, I would be glad. If you could afford to attach some linguistic references, I will appreciate your kindness.

Thank you for reading.

【 References 】

Dalzell, Tom and Terry Victor (Eds.) (2013) *The New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English Volume II: J-Z*, 2nd edition, Routledge, London.

*Genius English-Japanese Dictionary*, 5th edition (GEJD5) (2014) Taishukan Shoten, Tokyo.

Inoue, Tohru (2017) “Kantanshi toshiteno As If no Gohoo” (Remarks on Exclamatory As If), *The Seijo Bungei: the Seijo University Arts and Literature Quarterly* 240, 468-455, Seijo University.

Manser, Martin H. (1983) *A Dictionary of Contemporary Idioms*, Macmillan LanguageHouse, London.

*Oxford Advanced Learner’s Dictionary of Current English*, 9th edition (OALDCE9) (2015), Oxford University Press, Oxford.

*Oxford Dictionary of English*, 3rd edition (2010) Oxford University Press, Oxford.

*Oxford English Dictionary*, 3rd edition (2010-) http://www.oed.com/.

Tunnicliffe, Luke (2013) *Igirisu no Surangu, Amerika no Surangu: Eigo with Luke* (British Slang, American Slang: English with Luke), Kenkyusha, Tokyo.

Comment: What do you mean by *page* 90 of the third edition of the Oxford English Dictionary?

Comment: Are you claiming there is a "radical difference"?

Comment: Also, the usual acronym is OALD-9, not OALDCE.

Comment: As with @JeremyNeedle, I don't see where in this data you're getting the suggestion that there's any particular difference.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, @Alex B. Oxford Dictionary of English is completely different from Oxford English Dictionary. (See "References")

Comment: And Thank you, Alex, for your advice of the general acronym.

Comment: Because I'm not a native English speaker, I thought that  there's some radical difference. But actually only slight difference, right?

Comment: Sorry, didn't read carefully enough. Of course, I know that the OED and ODE are completely different dictionaries.